# To set a Time period for enabling and disabling the button

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have set a counter and when the counter value is zero the button will be disabled. But I want to re-enable it after 3minutes. so, how am I supposed to set a timer for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is you could use a handler that will run in 3 minutes

```
 Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    },3_MINUTES_IN_MILIS);
```

Comment: hey, i was disabling it inside the handler.. i shud have enabled it there.
thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

okay. So when you disable the button, you can do this,

```
button.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //enable the button
            }
        }, 3 * 60 * 1000);
```

This code should be run from UI/Main thread

Answer (score 0):

When you disable the button, call this code

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler .postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
},3 * 60 * 1000);
```

Let me know if it solved your purpose.